# Query para copiar una tabla de una base de datos a otra enditando el contenido - Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

Es mi primera vez posteando aquí, y necesito ayuda.
Necesito una query que pueda copiar todo el contenido de una tabla **t1** de la base de datos **test1**, a la tabla **t2** de la base de datos **test2**, (las columnas son idénticas), donde la primaryKey **idNum** de *t1=1* y la **idNum** de *t2=2*, y que al copiar la tabla se edite la **idNum** de **t2** a la del destino en este caso 2.

En **t2.idNum** solo tengo una la 1, por lo tanto no se si se puede copiar a **t2.idNum** (la idNum 2) la cual no existe en el destino y la tengo que crear, editando la que copio de **t1** a la de destino.

Se puede hacer esto? Esque aún soy un poco novato con SQL, si no se puede, cómo copio una tabla entera dependiendo de su ID, a otra tabla idéntica, en una posición concreta establecida por su id, evitando redundancia (ya sea editándola o no)?

Lo que se me ha ocrurrido, que ni me sirve ni me va.

```
select * into test2.t2 where test2.t2.IdNum=2 from test1.t1 where test1.t1.idNum=1
```

El problema esta en que tengo mas de **400 campos** en ambas tablas, y poner todas en el INSERT INTO es muy tedioso, no hay otra manera?

El truncate no me sirve, ya que sólo necesito pasar una fila según el ID.

Y lo que decía de editar la PK es porque he de copiar una fila de **t1** donde la PK pueda ser 32 a **t2** donde la PK tenga que ser 2 por ejemplo, y no puede ser 32, ya que daria problemas, por lo tanto tendria que modificarla, y no se si se puede hacer en la misma query o debería usar otra manera.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No acabé de entender toda la pregunta, pero si lo básico.
Para obtener una referencia completa a los campos de una tabla en SQL Server debemos tener en cuenta cuatro nombres separados por puntos: 
NombreBaseDatos.Esquema.NombreTabla.NombreCampo. Rl esquema por defecto es el `dbo`

Para copiar toda la tabla t1 de la base de datos test1 a la tabla t2 de la base de datos t2 haríamos lo siguiente:

```
USE test1   --Esto es para utilizar esta base de datos
GO

INSERT INTO text2.dbo.t2 (IdNum, Campo1, Campo2, ...)
SELECT IdNum, Campo1, Campo2, ...
FROM t1
```

Si quieres copiar solo una fila, lo indicas en el where

```
INSERT INTO text2.dbo.t2 (IdNum, Campo1, Campo2, ...)
SELECT IdNum, Campo1, Campo2, ...
FROM t1
WHERE IdNum = 1
```

Si quieres cambiar el IdNum

```
INSERT INTO text2.dbo.t2 (IdNum, Campo1, Campo2, ...)
SELECT IdNum + 1, Campo1, Campo2, ...
FROM t1
```

Si lo que quieres es disponer en t2 de una copia exacta de t1, asegúrate antes de hacer el insert de eliminar los datos en el destino:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE text2.dbo.t2;
```